# KD TREES (3-D) Nearest Neighbour Search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, kdtree

I am looking at the Wikipedia page for **KD trees Nearest Neighbor Search**.

The pseudo code given in Wikipedia works when the points are in 2-D(x,y) .

I want to know,what changes should i make,when the points are 3-D(x,y,z).

I googled a lot and even went through similar questions link in stack overflow ,but i did n't find the 3-d implementation any where,all previous question takes 2-D points as input ,not the 3-D points that i am looking for.

The pseudo code in Wiki for building the KD Tree is::

```
function kdtree (list of points pointList, int depth)
{
    // Select axis based on depth so that axis cycles through all valid values
    var int axis := depth mod k;

    // Sort point list and choose median as pivot element
    select median by axis from pointList;

    // Create node and construct subtrees
    var tree_node node;
    node.location := median;
    node.leftChild := kdtree(points in pointList before median, depth+1);
    node.rightChild := kdtree(points in pointList after median, depth+1);
    return node;
}
```

How to find the Nearest neighbor now after building the KD Trees?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently coded up a KDTree for nearest neighbor search in 3-D space and ran into the same problems understand the NNS, particularly 3.2 of the wiki. I ended up using this algorithm which seems to work in all my tests:

Here is the initial leaf search:

```
public Collection<T> nearestNeighbourSearch(int K, T value) {
    if (value==null) return null;

    //Map used for results
    TreeSet<KdNode> results = new TreeSet<KdNode>(new EuclideanComparator(value));

    //Find the closest leaf node
    KdNode prev = null;
    KdNode node = root;
    while (node!=null) {
        if (KdNode.compareTo(node.depth, node.k, node.id, value)<0) {
            //Greater
            prev = node;
            node = node.greater;
        } else {
            //Lesser
            prev = node;
            node = node.lesser;
        }
    }
    KdNode leaf = prev;

    if (leaf!=null) {
        //Used to not re-examine nodes
        Set<KdNode> examined = new HashSet<KdNode>();

        //Go up the tree, looking for better solutions
        node = leaf;
        while (node!=null) {
            //Search node
            searchNode(value,node,K,results,examined);
            node = node.parent;
        }
    }

    //Load up the collection of the results
    Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>(K);
    for (KdNode kdNode : results) {
        collection.add((T)kdNode.id);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Here is the recursive search which starts at the closest leaf node:

```
private static final <T extends KdTree.XYZPoint> void searchNode(T value, KdNode node, int K, TreeSet<KdNode> results, Set<KdNode> examined) {
    examined.add(node);

    //Search node
    KdNode lastNode = null;
    Double lastDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    if (results.size()>0) {
        lastNode = results.last();
        lastDistance = lastNode.id.euclideanDistance(value);
    }
    Double nodeDistance = node.id.euclideanDistance(value);
    if (nodeDistance.compareTo(lastDistance)<0) {
        if (results.size()==K && lastNode!=null) results.remove(lastNode);
        results.add(node);
    } else if (nodeDistance.equals(lastDistance)) {
        results.add(node);
    } else if (results.size()<K) {
        results.add(node);
    }
    lastNode = results.last();
    lastDistance = lastNode.id.euclideanDistance(value);

    int axis = node.depth % node.k;
    KdNode lesser = node.lesser;
    KdNode greater = node.greater;

    //Search children branches, if axis aligned distance is less than current distance
    if (lesser!=null && !examined.contains(lesser)) {
        examined.add(lesser);

        double nodePoint = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double valuePlusDistance = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        if (axis==X_AXIS) {
            nodePoint = node.id.x;
            valuePlusDistance = value.x-lastDistance;
        } else if (axis==Y_AXIS) {
            nodePoint = node.id.y;
            valuePlusDistance = value.y-lastDistance;
        } else {
            nodePoint = node.id.z;
            valuePlusDistance = value.z-lastDistance;
        }
        boolean lineIntersectsCube = ((valuePlusDistance<=nodePoint)?true:false);

        //Continue down lesser branch
        if (lineIntersectsCube) searchNode(value,lesser,K,results,examined);
    }
    if (greater!=null && !examined.contains(greater)) {
        examined.add(greater);

        double nodePoint = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double valuePlusDistance = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        if (axis==X_AXIS) {
            nodePoint = node.id.x;
            valuePlusDistance = value.x+lastDistance;
        } else if (axis==Y_AXIS) {
            nodePoint = node.id.y;
            valuePlusDistance = value.y+lastDistance;
        } else {
            nodePoint = node.id.z;
            valuePlusDistance = value.z+lastDistance;
        }
        boolean lineIntersectsCube = ((valuePlusDistance>=nodePoint)?true:false);

        //Continue down greater branch
        if (lineIntersectsCube) searchNode(value,greater,K,results,examined);
    }
}
```

The full java source can be found [here](http://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/4d08a6ab52a90502a91f7789e6f0fc4f6d6ab037/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/KdTree.java).

Answer (score 5):

You find the nearest neighbour exactly as described on the Wikipedia page under the heading "Nearest neighbour search". The description there applies in any number of dimensions. That is:

- Go down the tree recursively from the root as if you're about to insert the point you're looking for the nearest neighbour of.
- When you reach a leaf, note it as best-so-far.
- On the way up the tree again, for each node as you meet it:

  - If it's closer than the best-so-far, update the best-so-far.
  - If the distance from best-so-far to the target point is greater than the distance from the target point to the splitting hyperplane at this node,
  - process the other child of the node too (using the same recursion).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know,what changes should i make,when the points are
>   3-D(x,y,z).

You get the current axis on this line

```
var int axis := depth mod k;
```

Now depending on the axis, you find the median by comparing the corresponding property. Eg. if axis = 0 you compare against the x property. One way to implement this is to pass a comparator function in the routine that does the search.